# Create a folder called 'work' automatically when a new user is created

Tags: windows, windows-7, server, window

How can I configure the system so that whenever we register a new user, automatically available on her/his desktop directory called "work"?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the folder under C:\Users\Default\Desktop, for all new users, this will be avilable. Or am I missing the point here?

Alternatively use a group-policy to create this for all new users.